# MY ADB.exe failed to start

Tags: adb

I have tried adb start-server and it is showing:

> daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037
>   error: Cannot open 'C:\Users\r\Appdata\Local\Temp\adb.log': Permission denied could not read ok from ADB server
>   * failed to start daemon *
>   error: cannot connect to daemon

[image: error]

Comment: Try running the command prompt as administrator instead. Right click on the Command Prompt in your start menu and choose "Run as Administrator".

Comment: I have tried command prompt running as administrator but then also it is not working.